# Zapier CLI: How to retrieve {{zap_meta_human_now}} ISO 8601 timestamp from running Zaps

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am creating a Zapier integration using the Zapier CLI and I need my Action to retrieve, as an input (stored in the `bundle` object), the ISO 8601-formatted time that the Zap which includes the action runs. I know how to ask the user to input `{{zap_meta_human_now}}` into a datetime input field to send the current ISO 8601-formatted datetime to the Action; however, I want to put this ISO-8601 datetime string in the `bundle` object *without* asking the user to input it.

How can I do this? Is there a way to set an input field as "hidden" with a default value of "`{{zap_meta_human_now}}`", so that the timestamp is generated and input to the action each time a Zap runs? Is the `{{zap_meta_human_now}}` datetime string stored in the bundle object automatically? If so, how do I retrieve it in the CLI code?

I *could* put a regular datetime input field with a default value of `{{zap_meta_human_now}}` and a helpText of "DO NOT CHANGE THIS FIELD", but that seems like a terrible way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the ISO time for when the zap runs, then you can use the regular JS `new Date().toISOString()` in your `perform` function. That'll execute each time the zap runs and will always be current. No need to read it from `bundle.inputData`.